# NuxtJS customizable template engine instead of SFC <template>

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

NuxtJS or VueJS runs by creating SFC files with `<template>` and `<script>` tags in it.

What I want to achieve is an API/Dashboard backend with template support so an author goes into dashboard and change some template files, backend caches it and so Vue can grab that responsible `html` string like `layout/default.html` or `header/logo.html` and render it instead of using `<template>` tag in SFC.

Can it be done with NuxtJS, do I need to have express like backend tool to render html into string so can Nuxt somehow grab that and parse it (is it possible)?

Comment: You're looking into render functions maybe? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: is render function async? may I call api request in it?

Comment: Rendering a template a synchronous action so far. It all comes down on you handle this at the end.